# call function between classes

Tags: c++, oop, linux, class

hello
I have 3 classes  class A, B, and C

class A is the main class and content the main function also, i call class B and class C in the main as b1,b2 and c1.

in class B there is a vector (V) has list of int. and 3 functions Add, get and delete delete. all the thing in the class is public.

in class C i have function that need to (B::get) from b.

what I want is that how I can make c1 call get of b1 to return the value of the V in b1 after that use add of b2 to add new item in V of b2.
Thanks in advance

This is an example

```
class a{
    int main(){
        b b1,b2;
        c c1;
        b1.add(10);
        b1.add(20);
        c1.start();
    }}

class b{
    vector<int> v;
    void add(int i){
        v.push_back(i)}
    int get(){int i=v.at(0); return i;}
    }

class c{// take something from b1 and add it to b2
    void play(){
        int i=b.get();//should take it from b1
        b.add(i*2);//should add it to b2
    }}
```

please I need your help I been searching to solve this problem for days.

Comment: I honestly do not know what you are asking.

Comment: @Pemdas: how to make 2 class call each other and share the data between there self

Comment: This code does not compile.  I see at least 2 different syntax errors.

Comment: Are you learning C++ from a Java background by chance?

Comment: @abelenky this is an example only the code is too big for example the class b is 600 lines.

Comment: @chris no i dont have a java background i have simple knowkage about c/c++ java python and vb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `play` wants to do things that depend on `b1` and `b2`, they are *parameters* of `play`.
Like this:

```
class c
{
public:
    void play(const b& oneB, b& otherB)
    {
        int i = oneB.get();
        otherB.add(i * 2);
    }
}

int main()
{
    b b1, b2;
    c c1;
    b1.add(10);
    b1.add(20);
    c1.play(b1, b2);
}
```

We're passing references (`&`) because your lexer and tokenizer most likely have internal state and you don't want to copy them but use the same objects.

Note that this is C++, not Java, so the `main` function is global, not a member function of some class.

Another possibilty is to let the other objects be part of c's state:

```
class c
{
public:
    c(const b& oneB, b& otherB) : m_b1(oneB), m_b2(otherB) {}
    void play()
    {
        int i = m_b1.get();
        m_b2.add(i * 2);
    }
private:
    const b& m_b1;
    b& m_b2;
}

int main()
{
    b b1, b2;
    c c1(b1, b2);
    b1.add(10);
    b1.add(20);
    c1.play();
}
```

Since you're having problems with very basic concepts, I suggest you pick up a good book on C++ - you can find lists here on SO if you search for them.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your question is to give class C a reference/pointer to two different class b objects.

Then you can simply write

```
class c{// take something from b1 and add it to b2
    void play(){
        int i=b1.get();//should take it from b1
        b2.add(i*2);//should add it to b2
    }}
```

Comment: how i can do that when i try that the compiler shows error of not declared b1 and b2.

Answer (score 0):

Class c needs to store a reference to b1 and b2.

```
class c{
public:
    c(b& b1, b& b2): m_b1(b1), m_b2(b2) {}
    void play(){
        int i=m_b1.get();
        m_b2.add(i*2);
    }
private:
    b& m_b1;
    b& m_b2;
};

class a{
    int main() {
          b b1,b2;
          c c1(b1, b2);
          b1.add(10);
          b1.add(20);
          b1.play();
    }
```

Basically, when an object needs to use the functionality of another object (no matter if it is an instance of the same class or another), you need that class to get a handle to the object, i.e. a pointer or a reference.